# A theorem of change of variable on submanifolds

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

I am looking for a proof (or a link to a book or pdf) of the following result :

> If $\phi : S \to S'$ is a differentiable map between two compact, connected oriented $2$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $f$ an integrable function on $S'$, then : $$\int _S f \circ \phi (p) \operatorname{Jac} (\phi) (p) \mathrm{d}p = \int_{S'} f(q) \operatorname{deg} (\phi,q)\mathrm{d}q$$ where we define for $q$ such that $q$ is a regular value :$$\operatorname{deg} (\phi, q) := \sum_{p \in \phi ^{-1} (\{q\})} \varepsilon _{\phi} (q)$$ with $\varepsilon _{\phi} (q) = \operatorname{sgn} (\operatorname{Jac} (\phi) (q))$

Anybody has encouter this result ?

N.B. I have no notions af differential forms, my knowledge in differential geometry is basic.

EDIT. First we have to justify the definition of $\operatorname{deg} (\phi,q)$. In fact, when $q$ is regular $\phi ^{-1} (\{q\})$ is finite since it is a compact discrete set (compact because it is closed in a compact, and discrete by an elementary application of the local inversion theorem).
I don't know if it is useful but I know that with those definitions : $$\deg \phi = \frac{1}{Area(S')} \int_{S'} \deg (\phi ,q) \mathrm{d} q$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a special version of a theorem on the degree of map. Your can refer to [Nigel Hitchin's Lecture note](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinnotes/Differentiable_manifolds/manifolds2012.pdf) for a proof of the general case(Theorem 8.3).

Comment: Thanks. Before accepting I will read in details the proof !

Comment: In fact I don't know the differential forms. My course does not provide them. Thus it is not really a proper answr to me. I think that the lecture notes are at a too advanced level for me :(